# Magento 2 Session Expire after return from payment gateway

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, session, payment-gateway, magento2ccavenue

**We are facing the session expire issue, while, return from payment gateway.**

We are integrated CCavenue Magento 2.3.4 [Toolkit](https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/CCAvenue_MCPG_Magento_2-3-x.zip),

we are tried following ways

1. Cache => somebody told maybe problem of cache content checkout and cart pages, so we tried to disable full page cache, then tried.
2. Cookie Domain Mismatch => we are given the right hostname in cookie configuration.
3. Stickie Session => we follow this [blog](https://blog.benpri.me/blog/2019/05/13/samesite-cookies-in-practice/#:%7E:text=SameSite%20has%20two%20modes%20that,at%20all%2C%20ever%2C%20period), they suggested to use SameSite=lax.

Still, the session expires, after return from the payment gateway. we debug our toolkit, the session is there, before redirected to the payment gateway. after return from payment gateway only. session expires.

Suggest me, what is the issue and how to fix this.

Comment: Facing same issue with CCavenue (2.3.7) in Magento 2.4.1 where the user is getting redirected to the empty page and being logged out instead of being shown the OnePage Checkout Sucess Page.

Comment: @RoydenRego I have posted my answer, pls check that

Comment: If you are using a custom order email confirmation template check that your order confirmation email is not calling any custom templates - to test switch back to the default confirmation email template. I had an issue where the confirmation email was clearing the session due to a call to a phtml template in the email.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is Chrome 80+ and all other modern browsers, they are updating their cookie policy. The cookie policy is **Third-Party not going to access the current browser cookie**.

So, We are using any third party plugins like payment gateway, while payment its redirected to their payment gateway only. when come back to our merchant site, merchant site not allowed to use cookie information. Thats why, we are facing that issue.

It Means, Moden browsers `SameSite=Lax by default`, If SameSite=Lax by default means, Merchant site not allow to use cookies for third party sites.

So, We have to set `SameSite=None; Secure` for the thrid party pages. Then only third party site can assess the session and update the order status.

After searching regarding this issue.

I have found a partial [solution](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26377) from Magento GitHub to update some core code. For my project, I am using the following configuration.

`Magento 2.4.1, PHP 7.3 and Apache 2.4`

Goto this file `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\SensitiveCookieMetadata`

```
protected $request;


public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, $metadata = [])
{
    if (!isset($metadata[self::KEY_HTTP_ONLY])) {
        $metadata[self::KEY_HTTP_ONLY] = true;
    }

    // PATCH
    $this->request = $request;

    if (!isset($metadata[self::KEY_SAME_SITE])) {
        // $metadata[self::KEY_SAME_SITE] = 'Lax';
        $isSecure = $this->getSecure();
        $metadata[self::KEY_SAME_SITE] = $isSecure ? 'None' : 'Lax';
    }
    //~ PATCH
    parent::__construct($metadata);
}
```

For Apache, add below script in .htaccess file located at root directory

```
 <If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-2]|iPad; CPU OS 1[0-2]|iPod touch; CPU iPhone OS 1[0-2]|Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X.*Version\x2F1[0-2].*Safari|Macintosh;.*Mac OS X 10_14.* AppleWebKit.*Version\x2F1[0-3].*Safari|(Chrom[^ \x2F]+\x2F(([4-5][0-9])|([6][0-7]))[\.\d]*[ ]))/i">
   Header always edit Set-Cookie "^(.*)(;[ ]?SameSite=None|;[ ]?samesite=None)(.*)?$" "$1$3"
 </If>
```

For Nginx, with this code you can define all your application cookies as secure, httponly and/or samesite using proxy_cookie_path (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path)

```
location / {
    # your usual config ...
    # hack, set all cookies to secure, httponly and samesite (strict or lax)
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none";
}
```

For PHP 7.3 and above, set following configuration in php.ini file

```
session.cookie_samesite = "None"

session.cookie_secure = 1
```

After that, run that following commands and try it out.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 

php bin/magento indexer:reindex 

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

then, see, `Inspect elements` in browser, For that third party pages only you can see `SameSite=None; Secure` and all other pages use `SameSite=Lax`. Then yor are configuration is right. its will works fine.

Comment: Third party payment gateways create their own cookies and sessions - this is nothing to do with Magento - and is not accessed by Magento. The Magento customer session should remain when returned from the payment gateway and cannot be changed by the payment gateway.

Comment: This fix also requires adding this `if ($secure) { $this->set(self::KEY_SAME_SITE, 'None');  }` condition before the return statement to the `setSecure` function of the `Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PublicCookieMetadata.php` file.